# Calendar module in drupal 7 question

Tags: 7, views, datetime

Can anyone help me with the following?

I want to let users of my site book a visit to my office by clicking on the time or on a button somewhere on the calendar day view.

This is the scenario:

a. The user can navigate to an empty calendar showing times from 9 am to 6pm (9.00 - 10.00, 10.00 - 11.00 etc). The user can see available times and book the hour he wants.

b. For every blank hour the calendar says "Available Time" and when an hour is booked says "Unavailable".

c. The user clicks on the desired hour and books it.

Though I said a lot, the question is simple.

This functionality is exactly the opposite from registering to an event, because the event is created by the user that books the hour. I mean that there are not events that the user registers for.

So how can the user do this and the show the hour as booked?

Comment: have you looked at the following modules? http://drupal.org/project/agreservations, http://drupal.org/project/availability_calendars

Comment: Thanks for your response! I will try them and tell the results!

Comment: Sorry for the delay! Unfontunatelly these need to much modifications to fit my project. I figured out how to do it if I manage to isolate the time field from date and make it have only the .00 option in the minute field! Any ideas?